# Does this Socket.IO code create a blocked connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, evented-io

The general rule in writing Node.js code is that all code should be non-blocking and communicate via events. I would like to know if this code written using the Socket.IO library for Node.js create a blocked connection, or does it follow the general Node.js rules?

```
sio.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (msg) {
    console.log("Received message"+message);
  });

  socket.on('cookie', function (msg) {
    console.log("Cookie Received");
    console.log(msg);
  });

  this.send('hello');


  socket.on('disconnect', function (){
    console.log('Disconnected');
  });
});
```

Would be grateful for any help.

Comment: It sets up a server, just like http.createServer( function )

Comment: You can't do any blocking(okay you can, but that is just stupid => while(true) ;) when coding javascript. But when you create c extension you can program blocking code which is bad!

Answer (score 2):

no, node.js socket.io server listens tcp with standard node non-blocking api

That is, your control goes immediately to next statement after `sio.sockets.on(..);`, the only thing happen in this call is 'construct javascript function object abd assign to listeners array'.